# Print to default printer in chrome headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, printing, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running chrome in headless mode using selenium for python.
`--kiosk-printing` argument is added to skip print preview
Everything is working fine except for printing.

This is how I start chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,720')
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Then I load my html to chrome

```
driver.get("https://localhost:5007/test_print.html")
```

The html has `window.print()` method

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Printing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Test Test</h1>
    </body>
    <script>
        window.print();
    </script>
</html>
```

This works when I remove headless option and keep selenium in the screen. **So my question is 'IS THERE ANY WAY TO PRINT A DOCUMENT IN CHROME HEADLESS MODE?'**

My purpose is to print a bill in a kiosk. My main webapp is on chrome kiosk mode. First I just loaded the bill to a hidden iframe but it shows the print preview for a less than one second which distracts user from the app. I want to print my bill 100% silently in a kiosk.

Comment: Looks for the same question if anyone found soultion for it

Comment: Currently I'm opening the chrome window at the edge of the screen, so the preview won't be shown. (This is not a genuine solution but couldn't find a better solution yet)